# Does ruby have something similar to buildout or virtualenv?

Tags: python, ruby, virtualenv, buildout

I was wondering:

In python, canon says to use buildout or virtualenv, to avoid installing into the system packages.  It's second nature now, I no longer see anything ludicrously bizarre to the practice.  It makes a kind of sense.

In Ruby, is there something similar?  How does ruby deal with this problem?  Does ruby have this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby equivalent of virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486995/ruby-equivalent-of-virtualenv)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several projects trying to handle this issue:

- [rip](http://github.com/defunkt/rip#readme)
- [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)
- [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) via [gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/)
- [sandbox](http://github.com/nkryptic/sandbox#readme)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer only covers one aspect of zc.buildout, which is the encapsulation of the environment. But zc.buildout is also about deployment/configuration of an application in a deterministic way, which these tools don't seem to provide.

Comment: as per status in 2023, all projects are stale and outdated