# Micro Virtual Machine Unix?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine

Is there a way to create and use "Micro Virtual Machines" on Unix ?

For example to keep an entire environ for Ruby Rails (rails versio, ruby...) that we can mount on a unix system ?

I'm not speaking about heavy-weight Virtualization as VmWare, Proxmox but a lighter system to virtualize an environment of programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `virtualenv` in Python world for such things so I think this will help you: [Ruby equivalent of virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486995/ruby-equivalent-of-virtualenv)

Comment: @tknew, if the answer was so helpful, may be it is worth accepting? Anyway, the decision is yours.

Comment: Yesterday I couldnt do it because the delay between the question and the answer was to short.