# Does gem isolate like pipsi?

Tags: python, ruby, pip, rubygems, package-managers

`pipsi` allows you to install Python apps with isolated dependencies. It doesn't just isolate the dependencies (like `virtualenv`), the apps are also immediately executable (like `pip`). For example:

```
pipsi install foo # has strict dependency on Xv1.0
pipsi install bar # has strict dependency on Xv2.0
foo --version # works immediately
bar --help # works immediately
```

I need to install some Ruby tools using `gem`. Does gem offer similar isolation? In other words:

```
gem install foo # has strict dependency on Xv1.0
gem install bar # has strict dependency on Xv2.0
foo --version # works immediately
bar --help # works immediately
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an software tool are generally off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. With that being said, about all Rubyists use [bundler](https://bundler.io/) which can be instructed to install any dependencies to a separate directory instead of the global gemset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby equivalent of virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486995/ruby-equivalent-of-virtualenv)

Comment: @holger thanks for your comment, I'm asking for a direct comparison between pipsi and gem, not a recommendation, is there an error in my ruby terminology? it sounds like the answer to my question is simply "no" (but the hint about a possible solution is welcome  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `gem` does not isolate packages like `pipsi`. It simply installs gem dependencies, the Ruby equivalent of Python's `pip`.

Like `pip`, anything you install with `gem` is immediately executable (if applicable). So you can:

```
gem install foo
foo --help
```

...but dependencies between `foo` and `bar` are not isolated.

Comment: You might be interested in [bundler](https://bundler.io) for isolation (as suggested by Holger in the comments above), but that works more like `pipenv` than `pipsi`