# $GEM_HOME is ignored by `gem install`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables

I have `$GEM_HOME` set, but `gem install` is still installing to the default `~/.gem` directory.

[This rubygems issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/687) says to remove the `--user-install` option in `.gemrc`, but I don't have a `.gemrc` file.

How can I get `gem install` to honour the value of `$GEM_HOME`?

---

Here I firstly remove `~/.gem`, and then show that it is automatically created:

```
% rm -rf ~/.gem
% find ~ -name '*gemrc*'    
% # No output, so .gemrc doesn't exist
% echo $GEM_HOME
/home/ravi/.local/share/gem
% gem install neovim
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed msgpack-1.2.7
Successfully installed multi_json-1.13.1
Successfully installed neovim-0.8.0
Parsing documentation for msgpack-1.2.7
Installing ri documentation for msgpack-1.2.7
Parsing documentation for multi_json-1.13.1
Installing ri documentation for multi_json-1.13.1
Parsing documentation for neovim-0.8.0
Installing ri documentation for neovim-0.8.0
Done installing documentation for msgpack, multi_json, neovim after 0 seconds
3 gems installed
% ls -ld ~/.gem
drwxr-xr-x 1 ravi ravi 8 Mar  9 12:34 /home/ravi/.gem/
```

Environment information:

```
% gem --version
3.0.2
% gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.1 (2019-01-30 patchlevel 33) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ravi/.local/share/gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ravi/.local/share/gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ravi/.cache/gem
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ravi/.local/share/gem
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--user-install"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ravi/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin
     - /home/ravi/bin
     - /home/ravi/.local/share/npm/bin
     - /home/ravi/.local/share/go/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     - /usr/bin/site_perl
     - /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
     - /usr/lib/systemd
     - /home/ravi/.local/share/miniconda3/bin
     - /home/ravi/.cabal/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     - /usr/bin/site_perl
     - /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
%
```

Comment: Your `gem env` shows `--user-install` is active. Where is this option coming from?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `rubygems` installed with `snap` (Ubuntu Software), which installs to `~/.gem` by default. I was able to change the install directory by using `--install-dir` switch

```
$ gem install --install-dir /path/to/custom/directory foo
```

However, I later had problems using the gems which I installed in a non-default directory.

**Uninstalling it and installing with `apt` solved all problems.**

```
$ sudo snap remove ruby
$ sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

Now, gems are always installed to `$GEM_HOME`. In order to still have `~/.gem` as default install location, add this to your init script (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin
```

To overwrite the install location, you just have to overwrite `GEM_HOME` before calling `gem install`.

Comment: This is a useful level of detail, and a good first answer. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1):

As Casper pointed out in the comment, my configuration was still getting `--user-install` from somewhere.

While my `~/.gemrc` didn't exist, I checked in `/etc/gemrc` and found the following:

> ```
> # --user-install is used to install to $HOME/.gem/ by default since we want to separate
> #                pacman installed gems and gem installed gems
> install: --user-install
> ```

To override this, I added to my `~/.gemrc`:

> ```
> install: --no-user-install
> ```

And now `$GEM_HOME` is respected.

Comment: It looks like you're using the [Pacman package manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman), which [intentionally separates](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ruby#Installing_gems_per-user_or_system-wide) user-installed gems from package manager installed gems to avoid conflicts. I suggest only installing gems via RubyGems, and none through Pacman.

Comment: This should probably be `install: --no-user-install` (`install` not `gem`).
https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

Comment: @TomHale literally just did.

Comment: Seems like it was rejected. I don't have time to review myself right now. If another comments your suggestion works I'll update it.

Comment: Unless you are somehow missing a terminal and a working gem executable, the time it would take is about a minute maybe. Probably less time than you've spent on commenting about not having time. Take my downvotes instead.

Comment: This does not work. It should be `install:` and not `gem:`.